# Swift Playground and Procreate exercise - Ipad Camera Won't Open

Tags: ios, ipad, camera

any answer to that?

I just tested the Swift Playgrounds app with a exercise that Procreate App gave at their website in a partnership the artist @jaromvogel.

In the end of the exercise, they teach us to upload our drawings in layers and separate them with depth, so we can see the art in the Augmented Reality.

But in the end, the SP app ask for the permission to use the Ipad Camera, I gave it, but it wont open to finally test in the real world.

Anyone know how to solve that?

Comment: Stackoverflow is more about code problems than software issues, i think superuser is the stackexchange you are looking for

Comment: Ah ok! Thanks for the reply! I new at this area and coding, so Im getting used hehe
I will look those up too! Thanks!

About the issue: I figured that the background image I was using, wasn't working with SPlaygrounds. It was a flat colour, but I tryed a white background + some black shapes on it and it worked. I don't know why, but it worked. Also talked about it with @jaromvogel and he said the same stuff... So now Im trying to figure out how to turn the background invisible and then use new layers as the desired background..

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your canvas at Procreate is 1000px and 1000 (or 1300) px before you export your layers to png files!
I had the same problem and when I changed the canvas it worked  hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried it, even with less then 1000px, but it didnt worked. I figure out that the background I was using, which was just a flat colour, was doing that. And then I changed to a simple but with shapes one, with more contrast (black and white shapes) and it worked!